# action_scheduler not cancelling recurring action while running

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action-scheduler

I am building a plugin with action_scheduler but unable to cancel a recurring action inside its hook execution while running.

I am using this code to cancel a recurring action to not run next until added again but its not cancelling the action and keeps scheduling:
`as_unschedule_action()`

But when I call above function `as_unschedule_action()` to cancel that same recurring action outside its hook/execution, then it works.

Please help me on it.

Thanks

### Edit

This is how I trying to do:

1. scheduling a recurring event using: `as_schedule_recurring_action(time(),'5min','test_action')` to run every `5min`
2. while this event's action running, I am cancelling this recurring event using `as_unschedule_action('test_action')` so that it'll stop to run again, but its still scheduling and keeping running.

Comment: Apparently, using `as_unschedule_action()` or any other schedule action function in a hooked function triggered by schedule action function, doesn't work… You should try to search and report this to the related [Action Scheduler plugin support pages](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/action-scheduler/)